# implementation of Weblaf on Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I have Just installed WebLaf and integrated it to Netbeans 7.2.1. However, am finding it difficult it identifying the icons as it only shows file icons. Am guessing I downloaded/integrated it wrongly?

Answer (score -1):

Following your request for help about your problem implementation of a custom look and feel, I could offer this solution :

```
try
{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel ( "com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel" );
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)
{
}
```